# CSS en WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

Soy nueva con `WordPress` y he creado mi propio plugin pero quiero ponerle el `CSS` en un archivo aparte. El problema es que no lo reconoce y no sé qué hago mal.

Si lo pongo en una etiqueta `style` en `HTML` no hay problema; el problema es al intentar ponerlo en otro archivo.

Pongo el código:

```
uno{float:left; background-color:;  padding: 10px; display: inline-block;}
#dos{float:left; background-color:; padding: 10px; display: inline-block;}

<!-- language: lang-html -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="estilo.css" />
```

y donde creo que está el problema:

```
<?php

    /*
    * Add my new menu to the Admin Control Panel
    */

    // Hook the 'admin_menu' action hook, run the function named 'mf_Add_My_Admin_Link()'
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'mf_Add_My_Admin_Link' );
    add_action (  'wp_enqueue_scripts' ,  'add_estilos'  );

    // Add a new top level menu link to the ACP
    function mf_Add_My_Admin_Link()
    {
        add_menu_page(
            'Tu Web', // Title of the page
            'Tu Web', // Text to show on the menu link
            'manage_options', // Capability requirement to see the link
            plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/tw-first-acp-page.php', // The 'slug' - file to display when clicking the link
            '','',3
            );
    }

    function add_estilos ()  { 
        wp_enqueue_style ('estilo' , get_template_directory_uri () . '/estilo.css', false); 
    }    

?>
```

Me coloca el plugin en el menú, lo abre y se carga perfectamente pero sin el `CSS` que yo especifico.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: ¿Has verificado la ruta de `estilo.css` mediante un `echo`?  si lo tienes en el plugin será otra ruta diferente a la del template.

Comment: La cuestión es saber ¿en qué directorio tienes el archivo `estilo.css`? Porque dependiendo de eso habrá que saber dónde buscarlo cuando haces `wp_enqueue_style`. Lo normal sería que esté en una carpeta `css` de tu propio plugin, entonces habría que hacer algo así: `wp_enqueue_style( 'miEstilo', plugins_url( '/css/estilo.css', __FILE__ ) );` Ojo, no pongas archivos de tu plugin fuera de su directorio, si se desinstala el plugin esos archivos se quedarán pululando por el WP o habrá que borrarlos manualmente, hacer eso sería programa un *dirty plugin*  que deja trazas al desinstalarlo.

Comment: Probado, la ruta que pongo es la correcta. Pero he observado que si pongo un echo dentro de la función add_estilos NO veo que lo muestre, ¿puede no entrar?

Answer (score 0):

Esta función es altamente sospechosa:

**get_template_directory_uri ()**

Ya que no se trata de un theme sino de un plugin.

Prueba a cambiarla por esto:

**plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'nombredetuplugin/estilo.css'**

Comment: no sería `plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/estilo.css'` ?  el nombre del plugin ya lo devolvería la función (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/#comment-491)